# Reading XML with jQuery - I want only the first entry/node

Tags: jquery, xml

In my XML file I've got multiple entries for `satz`:

```
var aufz = $(this).find('satz').text()
```

How can I get just the first entry/node? I tried:

```
var aufz = $(this).find('satz[1]').text()
```

but it won't work. Thanks for your help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "saetze.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('kategorie[id="aufzaehlung"]').each(function() {
                var aufz = $(this).find('satz').text()
                $('<p class="aufz"></p>').html(aufz).appendTo('.aufz');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I would try:

```
$(this).find('satz').eq(0).text();
```